# Can we attach a file to gmail using pyautoit module?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, gmail, attachment

```
import os
import sys
import selenium
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
Get_webpage=browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?sacu=1&scc=1&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&hl=en&service=mail#identifier')

user_name = browser.find_element_by_id('Email')
user_name.send_keys("username")#Enter your username

time.sleep(2)

next = browser.find_element_by_id('next')
next.submit()

time.sleep(5)

password = browser.find_element_by_id('Passwd')
password.send_keys("password")#enter your password
password.submit()

time.sleep(5)
compose = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='button']")
compose.click()

time.sleep(5)
Attach_file = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@role='button']")
```

I was able to login to gmail.I was able to compose a mail but I am not able to attach any file.Can anyone suggest me a way to attach file?Is that possible with selenium or do I have to use pyautoit module?

Comment: While I respect the attempt to use selenium, why are you not using the google api? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/

Comment: I didn't know that we can use google api. Could you please guide me through how i can use it attach files while sending mails?Please not that i need to automate it using python not with java.

Comment: The link I posted has guides, samples, and plenty of documentation. The guides even have python examples. There is even a guide on "Uploading Attachments". So I think you just have to read and learn.

Comment: Thanks for that.What about upload a file to a website like submitting a resume to a career website using python selenium?

Comment: The problem with using selenium is that if the website changes even slightly, it can break your program. Better to see if they have a published API and use that. Plus if you use their API, you are not breaking their terms of service, which you might be if you are using a screen scraper.

Comment: So does each website has their own API?If so how do I find that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134525/discussion-between-sai-and-robertb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going a very difficult road here by trying to avoid the "right" way of doing things. Drop the current approach with selenium, and dive into the cold water, it's not that difficult.

This is a working example of sending an email with an attachment, once you understood `MIME`you can do whatever you want with mails.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email From Python'
msg['From'] = 'sai@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'whatever@whatever.com'

# That is what u see if dont have an email reader:
msg.preamble = 'Multipart massage.\n'

# This is the textual part:
part = MIMEText("Hello im sending an email with a PDF from a python program")
msg.attach(part)

# This is the binary part(The Attachment):
part = MIMEApplication(open("networkanalyze.pdf","rb").read())
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename="file.pdf")
msg.attach(part)

# Create an instance in SMTP server
smtp = SMTP("smtp.gmail.com:587")
smtp.ehlo()
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login("sai@gmail.com", "mySuperSecretPassword")
smtp.close()

# Send the email
smtp.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.Where do I have to mention the path to the file which i have to attach?

Comment: if the file is in same directory than your .py file, you dont have to mention the path. else you edit this line: 
`part = MIMEApplication(open("\path\to\file\networkanalyze.pdf","rb").read())`

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider voting it up/accepting as answer.